# Symfony 6 EasyAdmin 4 Field setPermission

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, easyadmin, symfony6

I am using EasyAdmin 4 (EA4) and I want to disable a field based on a value on the same entity.

For example, a **Reviewer** might be associated with a **User**, and in this case I want to disable other fields, like *name*.

So I created a **Voter** which gets the **Reviewer** and checks if `$reviewer->getUser() === null`.

However, I found out that it is not even possible to hide the *name* field correctly using `setPermission`, since the **Voter** gets a **FieldDTO** with no value.

So, I'm lost. How could I get this kind of behavior?

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution I found so far (I hope there's a better one):

```php
public function createEditForm(EntityDto $entityDto, KeyValueStore $formOptions, AdminContext $context): FormInterface
{
    if ($entityDto->getInstance()->getUser() !== null)
    {
        $entityDto->getFields()->getByProperty('name')->setFormTypeOption('disabled', true);
        $entityDto->getFields()->getByProperty('institution')->setFormTypeOption('disabled', true);
        $entityDto->getFields()->getByProperty('email')->setFormTypeOption('disabled', true);
    }
    return parent::createEditForm($entityDto, $formOptions, $context);
}
```

Comment: Better in which sense? Just asking, what options / alternatives are you looking for?

Comment: I understand, I was expecting some kind of `setDisabled` overload allowing us to use a callable or arrow function to set if the field should be disabled based on the entity. But I know there isn't such a feature. Using `createEditForm` is a bit obscure, and I think there's no documentation, right?